# Adding multiple Google Analytics trackerscodes

Tags: google-analytics

On my website I have a Google Analytics scripts with my own trackercode. One of my clients, who has its own pages on my website, wants to be able to see pageviews of those pages in my websites under his own GA account.
I have tried the following code:

```
ga('create', 'My-code', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'client code', 'auto');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But that doesn't seem to have the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two analytics on one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684498/two-analytics-on-one-page)

Comment: Ok, ik changed my code to this:
ga('create', my-code', 'auto', 'my-tracker');
ga('send', 'pageview');      
ga('create', 'client-code', 'auto', 'client-tracker');
ga('send', 'pageview');

But i still don't see the views in the Analytics portal